# Powershell-script to export array contents to excel

Tags: powershell

I am using the below script to export results to excel. However I am getting only 1 row when I am exporting it to excel.Please let me know how to acheive this.
 #script

```
$result = @()

$array = @("testA", "testB", "testC","testD")
$array2 = @("testA1", "testB2", "testC3","testD4")
$tbl = new-object psobject            
$tbl | add-member noteproperty VmName $array
$tbl | add-member noteproperty VMIP $array2
$result += $tbl 

$result|Export-Excel -Path "C:\Users\Empower\Desktop\OMS-Log\test.xlsx"
```

Console output:

```
VmName                                VMIP                            
------                                      ----                            
{testA, testB, testC, testD}     {testA1, testB2, testC3, testD4}
```

Exported result in Excel:

```
 VmName   VMIP
 testA    testA1
```

Required result in Excel

```
VmName  VMIP
testA   testA1
testB   testB2
testC   testB3
testD   testB4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating one object with two properties (each one is array). To export xlsx file you need four objects with two properties. It's sometimes called [zipping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
$array = @("testA", "testB", "testC","testD")
$array2 = @("testA1", "testB2", "testC3","testD4")

$result = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Zip($array,$array2,[Func[Object, Object, Object[]]]{
    [pscustomobject]@{VmName=$args[0];VMIP=$args[1]}
})

$result | Export-Excel -Path "C:\Users\Empower\Desktop\OMS-Log\test.xlsx"
```

Zip can also be expressed as:

```
$result = for ($i=0; $i -lt ([Math]::Min($array.Count, $array2.Count)); $i++) {
    [pscustomobject]@{VmName=$array[$i];VMIP=$array2[$i]}
}
```

Comment: From the question we know that we require four object.Could you please answer me this..I am trying to export logs to excel..I have 1 array with 17 properties,  since the number of logs keeps changing i dont know how many object  it would require